# Command Line From Java Program

Tags: java

I am trying to run a batch file from a Java program, and after the execution pass some arguments from Java program.

If I pass more than two arguments it doesn't work.

So how can I pass arguments one by one in running batch file through Java program?

```
String destDir = "D:\\JbossCacheFinal\\infinispan-server-8.1.1.Final\\bin\\ispn-cli.bat";


Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

String[] cmd = new String[2];

cmd[0] = destDir;
cmd[1] = "connect jboss1ind1";
// cmd[2] = "user.admin";
/*
 * cmd[3] = "Admin@123";
 * cmd[4] = "cd profile=clustered/subsystem=datagrid-infinispan/cache-container=clustered";
 * cmd[5] = "/distributed-cache=tejas:add(configuration=default)";
 */

Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
/* writer.write("connect jboss1ind1"); */

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

Thread.sleep(2000);

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

// read the output from the command
System.out.println("System returns message:\n");

String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Can you show as your error/ output message?

Comment: downvoted! Provide [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

It s because you try to open up an interactive session with your java program, as far as I see. Try to save those commands in batch file and execute your script from Java application.

Comment: do you have any example please send me ? please give me example to pass argument one by one in batch file

Comment: Sure, try this ; )

/path/to/my/program/myProgram.sh << EOF
MyCommand1
MyCommand2
EOF

Save it as bash file (for example script.sh) and make it executable (chmod 777 script.sh in terminal). Now you can execute it from Java just like you did :)